# How to use Azure KeyVault secret in SQL Connection string?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, powerbi, azure-keyvault

I have a SQL Azure instance and an associated user. 
The password of this user is stored as a Secret in Azure Key Vault.

Now, I have to hand over the connection string to this database to the Reports team for them to generate reports out of the database.

How can I hand this off so that the credentials are secure & the connection string does not actually store the password in a clear text format ?

Comment: Please refer to the following resource: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/56bed4bd-6320-4f1f-9af5-556ae91bdf0f/storing-sql-connection-string-passwords-in-key-vault-for-my-cloud-services

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use Azure AD Auth for your SQL instance.  Then you can create specific user accounts for the BI team.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication